# Very slow Windows 10 start up after changing from i7 to Xeon CPU

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, shutdown

I recently built a new computer using an E5 2683 v3 CPU; my old CPU was an i7-4790k. I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 Pro installed on different drives. Windows 10 is on a Samsung 850 Evo SSD, so it used to start up very fast. I have a [MSI X99A SLI Plus motherboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V4V4SFC) and I am using grub to select my OS when starting up.

I built a completely new computer, the only thing I brought over from the old computer was the storage devices, including the SSD my windows OS is on. It has always been on an SSD and with the new build it takes roughly 5 minutes to start, it used to take 10-15 seconds max. Ubuntu takes about the same time to start up compared to when it was in my old computer but is on a 1TB HDD. Also when I select shut down for Windows, shut down takes very long then it restarts the computer instead of just shutting it down.  I heard I will run into some issues going from an i7 to a Xeon but what is causing this and how do I fix it?

Complete specs:

- E5 2683v3 CPU
- Titan X(pascal) GPU
- 250 gb Samsung 850 EVO windows boot drive
- 2 x 1TB WD Blue drives, one for Ubuntu one for extra windows storage
- G.SKILL TridentZ Series 128GB 3200 mhz

Comment: It's not the CPU, it's the storage: 5 Minutes is completely normal for Win10 if run from a rotating drive.

Comment: It's running from an ssd

Comment: Please clarify: You just moved the SSD to a new build, and now the problem appears on the new machine? I read the question differently.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes of activity after boot. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze it and post what I can see from the trace